# Is there any metric for measuring the design effectiveness of a java web GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface, measurement

For a specific GUI of my java web application, some members of my team have designed different web GUIs. Each of the designed GUIs has its own pros and cons. Is there a metric to evaluate a web GUI and score each designed one a “goodness mark”? I want to pick up that GUI that has the highest score. Or any tools is available for this evaluation?

Comment: This should probably  be asked at [ux.stackexchange.com](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) to get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, because "goodness" means different things to different people.  On a web site you might measure that as how many people make it to the checkout though different interface variations, or how quickly they find a page they're looking for or how long they stay on the site etc.

You could measure some things against known standards, accessibility for example and there are some very general design principles (a grid layout is generally better than random jumble for example, consistency in placement and ordering of buttons is another).

If your application has a sufficiently high number of users to make a sensible sample size then a typical approach is [A/B testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) where you serve different versions of the interface to different people and see what happens.  However, you still need to decide on a goal to measure against (number of sales, time spent on site etc) to compare the two versions.

If you have a small user base or this is an internal application then direct user feedback might be the better option - i.e. just go and ask *them* which they find easier/better to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the "usefulness" vs "easy to use" metric.
[image]

Get some of your users sit down to rate UI with -10 to 10 on both variable, and plot them on the graph with different color, obviously more dots on top left is the better one.

I use this approach a lot as it can be done in like 10 minutes, and you can switch the "variable" depend on the project scope.

just my 2 cents

Answer (score 0):

Test it on real customers. The one they feel most content with is the one they are most likely to continue paying you for. That's the best GUI.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a personal call, depending on the intended purpose of the GUI, and its future users. If it's intended for sight-impaired people, I would use large and clear fonts and buttons, and possibly sound. It really depends on what you need.

You should make your own metric, and sort (or even give weights to) the options according to the desired preferences.

For accessibility, there are automatic tools, e.g. HTML Validator for firefox.